# Adwords Issue with Shopping Performance Reporting

Tags: php, google-reporting-api, google-ads-api

I am trying to get a list of products with some details from Shopping Performance Report. I was able to get the products with zero Impressions but in 49 products I can get through a specific campaign it only shows me 47.

I've been analysing the products data and there is, apparently, nothing different those 2 just don't appear.

```
 // Create selector.
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->setFields(
  [
    'OfferId',
    'Brand'
  ]
);

// Set the predicates array
$predicates = [];

// Predicates offerIds

// Predicates campaigns
if (!empty($campaignIds)) {
  $predicates[] = new Predicate('CampaignId', PredicateOperator::IN, $campaignIds);
}

// Predicates adgroups
if (!empty($adGroupIds)) {
  //$predicates[] = new Predicate('AdGroupId', PredicateOperator::IN, $adGroupIds);
}


// Global predicates
$predicates[] = new Predicate('Impressions', PredicateOperator::EQUALS, [0]);
//$predicates[] = new Predicate('CampaignStatus', PredicateOperator::EQUALS, ['ENABLED']);


// Use a predicate to filter out paused criteria (this is optional).
$selector->setPredicates($predicates);

$reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
$reportDefinition->setSelector($selector);
$reportDefinition->setReportName('Shopping report #' . uniqid());
$reportDefinition->setDateRangeType(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::ALL_TIME);
$reportDefinition->setReportType(ReportDefinitionReportType::SHOPPING_PERFORMANCE_REPORT);
$reportDefinition->setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat::CSV);

// Download report.
$reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader(parent::getSession());

// Set the Report Settings Builder
$reportSettingsOverride = (new ReportSettingsBuilder())
  ->skipReportHeader(true)
  ->skipColumnHeader(true)
  ->skipReportSummary(true)
  ->build();

// Download the report
$reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReport($reportDefinition, $reportSettingsOverride);

// Stores the stream
$reportStream = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();
```